# polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 fail to start in docker without privileged flag

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, centos6, apparmor

I'm using next docker gui container:

```
FROM centos:6

RUN yum -y install epel-release
RUN yum -y groupinstall "X Window System" "Desktop" "General Purpose Desktop"
RUN yum -y install openssh-server x2goserver x2goserver-xsession x2goserver-fmbindings x2goserver-printing pwgen
RUN yum reinstall glibc-common # fix some issues
RUN chkconfig sshd on
RUN sed -i "s/UsePAM.*/UsePAM no/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -i "s/#PermitRootLogin/PermitRootLogin/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN adduser vagrant
RUN echo 'root:vagrant' | chpasswd
RUN echo 'vagrant:vagrant' | chpasswd
RUN service sshd restart
RUN echo '#!/bin/bash' > /run.sh
RUN echo 'mkdir -p /tmp/.X11-unix' >> /run.sh
RUN echo 'chmod 1777 /tmp/.X11-unix' >> /run.sh
RUN echo 'service messagebus start' >> /run.sh
RUN echo 'exec /usr/sbin/sshd -D' >> /run.sh
RUN chmod +x /run.sh
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

And when I run it without `--privileged` flag, `polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` (`PolicyKit Authentication Agent` in Startup applications) failing to start and applications which require root permissions at some stage (for example `gpk-application` - `Add/Remove Software` menu item) could not get these permissions.

```
$ /usr/libexec/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1

(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:772): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: Unable to determine the session we are in: Remote Exception invoking org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GetSessionForUnixProcess() on /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager at name org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit: org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError: Unable to lookup session information for process '772' org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.GeneralError Unable%20to%20lookup%20session%20information%20for%20process%20%27772%27
```

I don't want to use `--privileged` flag, so I'm modifying desktop files for such application, adding `beesu` as workaround:

```
RUN yum -y install beesu
RUN sed -i "s/Exec=gpk-application/Exec=beesu gpk-application/g" /usr/share/applications/gpk-application.desktop
```

Which asking root password upfront (even when you don't need in this particular run) and triggers additional warning that gpk-application should not be run from root.

Is there better workaround (ideally which allows `polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` to run successfully)?

My docker host is Ubuntu 16.04 VM on ESXi 6.5, apparmor enabled. It looks to me that I need to enable some apparmor capability, but I don't see apparmor audit records in /var/log/kern.log.

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Wed Feb  8 06:50:14 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Wed Feb  8 06:50:14 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true

$ docker info
Containers: 15
 Running: 12
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 1083
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: zfs
 Zpool: zmain
 Zpool Health: ONLINE
 Parent Dataset: zmain/docker
 Space Used By Parent: 25711493632
 Space Available: 2017301029888
 Parent Quota: no
 Compression: on
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1
runc version: 9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-64-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 56
Total Memory: 147.6 GiB
Name: dockerl1
ID: 2QMS:5T3N:Y7CT:FFOK:A3PI:VGVB:WHW3:V43D:AHOD:MFX3:WB4C:6UBY
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 docker.acme.com
 registry-proxy.acme.com
 127.0.0.0/8
Registry Mirrors:
 registry-proxy.acme.com
Live Restore Enabled: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't see apparmor audit records, but found out that adding `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` to `docker run` resolves an issue, `polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` now running and applications which request root privileges after start working correctly.

I had to use another workaround to disable updater asking for root password after each connect:

```
RUN echo 'X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false' >> /etc/xdg/autostart/gpk-update-icon.desktop
```

And I've [asked separate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886887/how-to-enable-find-apparmor-logs-in-ubuntu-16-04) about apparmor.